# Dark mode css saving choice

Tags: javascript, css, local-storage

I recently made a dark mode on my website just like this > http://themes.semicolonweb.com/html/canvas/demo-articles.html

But as you can see when you refresh the page it will not save your choice, i want to save the choice with js and localstorage but can't make it work tho. 
If you have any suggestions for the localstorage here is my code :

```
    jQuery(document).ready( function($){
    function modeSwitcher( elementCheck, elementParent ) {

        if( elementCheck.filter(':checked').length > 0 ) {
            elementParent.addClass('dark');
            $('.mode-switcher').toggleClass('pts-switch-active');
        } else {
            elementParent.removeClass('dark');
            localStorage.toggled = "";
            $('.mode-switcher').toggleClass('pts-switch-active', false);
        }

    }

    $('.pts-switcher').each( function(){
        var element = $(this),
            elementCheck = element.find(':checkbox'),
            elementParent = $('body');

        modeSwitcher( elementCheck, elementParent );

        elementCheck.on( 'change', function(){
            modeSwitcher( elementCheck, elementParent );
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I don't see any localstorage in your code. Where did you try to add it? What didn't work

Answer (score 1):

Just giving you an idea here,

on the dark mode, button click save a local storage variable and the same do for light mode. on any theme, selection remove another local storage variable.
now on document.ready check the variable and apply class or CSS accordingly,
Due to snippet restriction you can not see this code in action here, but you can just pur this on your local and play with it, or just check this [codepen Link](https://codepen.io/atulraj89/pen/vYNZEGe).

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#dark').click(function(){
   localStorage.setItem('dark',true);
   localStorage.removeItem('light', false); 
   $('body').css("background-color", '#000');  
    });
    $('#light').click(function(){
   localStorage.setItem('light',true);
   localStorage.removeItem('dark',false); 
   $('body').css("background-color", '#fff');
    });
    var getLocalDarkVar = localStorage.getItem('dark');
    if(getLocalDarkVar == "true") {
     console.log("dark Theme");
     $('body').css("background-color", '#000');
    }else {
     console.log("Light Theme");
     $('body').css("background-color", '#fff');
    }

   });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="dark">Dark Mode</button>
 <button id="light">Light mode</button>
```